# My app opens login page but when i try to connect to server nothing happens on Mobile. But it works on emulator

Tags: java, android, connectivity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==btLogin)
        {   
            TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            try{
                mobileNo=Long.valueOf(etMobileNo.getText().toString().trim());
                password=etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                imeino=Long.valueOf(mngr.getDeviceId());
            }catch(NumberFormatException ne){
                errormessage=new StringBuilder("Invalid ");
                errormessage.append("Failed to parse id " + ne.getMessage());
            }
            if(etMobileNo.getText().toString().trim().startsWith("0") | etMobileNo.getText().toString().trim().length()<10 | etMobileNo.getText().toString().trim().equals("")| etPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Mobile No. & Password fields required",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{  
                System.out.println("Hello");
                try{
                    result=objCommonServices.authenticate(etMobileNo.getText().toString().trim(),etPassword.getText().toString().trim(),mngr.getDeviceId().toString()); 
                    System.out.println(result);   
                    if(result.contains("Err-"))
                    {
                        System.out.println(result);
                        Toast.makeText(this,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{

                        showDialog(0);
                        t = new Thread() {
                            public void run() {
                                register();
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(500);
                                    removeDialog(0);
                                    //   I want to show the dialog box like registered successfully after removing this dialog//
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        t.start();           
                    }


                }catch(Exception ne){}
            }}


void register()
    {
        try{
            String[] split1= result.split(":");
            uID= Integer.valueOf(split1[0]);
            objCommonBean.setuId(uID);
            objCommonBean.setPassword(password);
            objCommonBean.setMobileNo(mobileNo);
            objCommonBean.setDeviceId(imeino);
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable("objCommonBean",objCommonBean);   
            this.finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class).putExtras(b));
        }catch(Exception e){


}    // My Login Page


    }
```

//  My service page holds following

```
public String authenticate(String mobileNo, String password, String deviceId) {
        CommonBean objCommonBean=null;
        String result=null;
        //StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        //StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        DefaultHttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost request =new HttpPost("http://wsezypoint.ezypoint.org/eauthuzer.aspx");
        List<NameValuePair> param=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobileNo",mobileNo));
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei_no",deviceId));
                UrlEncodedFormEntity entity=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param);
                request.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                InputSource in = new InputSource(response.getEntity().getContent());
                InputStream isr=in.getByteStream();
               result= readData(isr);
}
```

I am unable to login from mobile but from emulator I can login. Is there need to implement Strict policy in services or there is problem in apk file ie. the file generated is wrong

Comment: What happens if you try to login from mobile?

Comment: Few days back I ran the same app but that was working fine. I signed the app & build it.

Comment: Did you check the logcat?

Comment: Then I copy the project and made another application with diffrent gui's.By doing same I created 5 more apps All of them run on emulator properly with good connectivity.

Comment: But not even a single app out of 5 is working on mobile.

Comment: In logcat no exception is there because it is working on emulator properly

Comment: You can check the logcat even if you run the app on the mobile device. You should try that. If you can't, you can add some `Toast`s to find out what happens. For example, use a `Toast` in the catch blocks additionally to the `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: put the attecnticate in doInBackground () of Asynctask. Some time internet is too slow then it not happen

Comment: connect your device and trace its logcat messages. Check if there is any value in the String 'result' by tracing it.

Comment: yes I did no toast appeared

Comment: I think my app is not able to reach to web server via mobile

Comment: That is possible and would explain why you don't get any toasts. But you still should get a timeout exception after some time.

Comment: My target API is 17 and i am running it on 15 Does this make any diffrence

Comment: It shouldn't. Did you check for timeout exceptions?

Comment: thanx Mr Torben for your suggestion of using AsyncTask class

Comment: Kindly tell me how to improve efficiency of app for connectivity

Comment: sunil suggested `AsyncTask`, not me ;) Did you solve the problem? I don't think you can improve connectivity by code... And it's a very general question that can't be answered easily.